# LazyList/LazyGrid is not recomposed

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3, android-compose-lazyfor

I have LazyList/LazyGrid that collects pagingData from room DB. when a column is updated the LazyList is not recomposing. it recomposes when we scroll the list a bit. then the Ui is updated.